# Ratio of two infinite series

Tags: co.combinatorics, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

After some highly non-rigorous calculations inspired by statistical physics, which are inconvenient to present here, I got the following result:

For integers $n \geq 1, a \geq 0, b \geq 0$. Define
$$
\begin{split}
A_n &= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{n^k}{k!} p(n, ka)\\
B_n &= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{n^k}{k!} p(n,ka+b)
\end{split}
$$
where
$$
p(n,j) = j!\binom{n}{j}n^{-j}
$$
is the probability that $j$ independent random elements from $\{1,\dots,n\}$ are distinct.
Then
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{B_n}{A_n} = t^b \label{1}\tag{$\ast$}
$$
where $t$ is the unique positive real number such that $t+at^a=1$.

It is simple to check \eqref{1} for $a=0$. For $a=1$, by applying $\partial_{x=1}^l$ on both sides of
$$
\sum_k \binom{n}{k}x^k = (1+x)^n
$$
it is easy to check that \eqref{1} also holds. I'm pretty convinced that \eqref{1} is correct. I've tried to prove it with Laplace's method but only got the log asymptotic of both infinite series.

Any idea how to prove (or disprove) this result?

Comment: look for which $k$ the summand $n^kp(n,ka)/k!$ in $A_n$ is maximal and close to maximal (that is seen from dividing two consecutive summands), and then look how does the corresponding summand in $B_n$ differ from it

Comment: @FedorPetrov Thanks.